# How do I set javaexec task debug options in kotlin dsl?

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

How do I translate this into kotlin dsl?

```
task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
  ...

  debugOptions {
     enabled = true
     port = 5566
     server = true
     suspend = false
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that many boolean objects in Kotlin DSL have `is` prefix in their names (e.g. `isEnbaled`). I was struggling with `lintOptions` configuration myself. Try changing option names.

Comment: I found the following kts code snippet somewhere, but I don't know where to put it: `debugOptions { enabled.set(true) suspend.set(false) }`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `java` plugin or the `kotlin("jvm")` plugin, you can do:

```
tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
    debugOptions {
        enabled.set(true)
        server.set(true)
        port.set(5005)
        suspend.set(false)
    }
}
```